# us citizen receiving bank transfer from foreign boyfriend

Tags: united-states, india, banking, scams

I have a boyfriend from India who has funds in Singapore and he wants to transfer several million dollars to my bank account before he comes to the US on a visitor visa.  We hope to get married when he comes and will use the funds to buy a home and start a business.  Do I have any tax exposure or problems with accepting this money?

Comment: You are being defrauded, no question. Have you ever met this person? They are going to try and claim funds from you ["you need to pay for my ticket" / "you need to pay the bank fees from within the US"], using the promise of love and money in return. **Do not continue contacting this person**.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a scam. Have you met in person. There is no money and he can transfer the money even after he reaches US

Comment: Why *before*?  I'd **strongly** urge him to transfer the money **after** you two are married.  (It'll make both governments much less suspicious of moving millions of dollars.)

Comment: See [Romance Scam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_scam)

Answer (score 12):

No, any gifts you receive are not taxable to you. In fact, losing money in a scam (as this sure sounds like to me) can even be tax-deductible if you lose enough!

I wouldn't recommend accepting anything. Usually people with millions are dollars are capable of setting up their own bank accounts.

Comment: Things are done differently in India, where arranged marriages are not uncommon.  (A number of guys I've worked with over the years went back to India specifically for a marriage to a woman they'd barely met.)  Thus, I would not dismiss her claims out of hand.

Comment: @RonJohn: It's not about the marriage, it's about the fact that somebody who supposedly has millions of dollars needs to use this person's bank account. There's no particular reason that it would need to happen before the marriage, and no particular reason that this person couldn't spend money out of his own bank account (in whatever country) until then.

Comment: Which is why in my comment to her question I strongly urged her to tell him to do this *after* he is here and they are married.

Comment: @RonJohn Prima Facie evidence in front of us is that someone travelling from another country "needs help with a bank account to transfer millions of dollars into". That means scam, 100%. This is not about cultural differences, this is not 'wait and see', this is a scam.

Comment: If it is truly a well-arranged marriage, then your parents should know his parents directly, have met, and talked at length, and have vetted each other.  Is this the case?  If there has not been extensive, face-to-face contact by reputable people, then ***THIS IS A SCAM.***

Comment: @abelenky "* Is this the case?*"  How do *we* know?  (But it might be, which is why I suggested what I suggested in my comment to her question.)

Comment: @RonJohn The reason your advice is possibly dangerous, is that there is a certain level of naivety required to be taken up by a scam. To recommend that someone 'go along' with the obvious scammer, and attempt to determine with proof that it's a scam (after many red flags are already raised), is putting that person in a position to continue to be influenced by the scammer. The more time such a person spends 'going along' with the scammer, the more likely they are to fall for it. Just like sending a gullible person to a time-share presentation can lead to them being tricked into a time share.

Comment: Nowhere have I written anything suggesting that she go along with what he wants.  I explicitly wrote, "Why *before*? I'd strongly urge him to transfer the money **after** you two are married."  That's pretty much the antithesis of "go along with what the guy wants".

Comment: @RonJohn Implying that the marriage may continue even though this person is clearly a scammer, is advice which a... optimistic person might take to mean "something seems a little off, but you should continue to pursue it".

Comment: This person **might** be a scammer.  If he insists on sending her the money, **and that she needs to send him transfer fees, etc** then we'll know he's a scammer.  Until then, I'll remain in the "he's just naive" camp.

Comment: @RonJohn If that's really what you believe then please follow me, I've got a wonderful bridge to sell you...

Comment: Grade, I'm already married, and the only people who want to send me money are (1) my employer, and (2) the widows of Nigerian princes.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I will not accept the money. Too risky

Answer (score 4):

> I have a boyfriend from India

He may be claiming to be your boyfriend, but it's far more likely he is a conman, trying to build up confidence with you so he can use you to further his ends. Exactly what those ends are is hard to say but it probablly won't end well for you.

> who has funds in Singapore and he wants to transfer several million dollars to my bank account

People who legitimately have that kind of money have plenty of options that poor and lower middle class people do not. Opening foreign bank accounts can be a problem for regular people but much less so for rich people.

> before he comes to the US on a visitor visa. We hope to get married when he comes and will use the funds to buy a home and start a business.

Theoretically it's possible to marry someone and adjust status after coming to the US on a visitor visa. However it is NOT legal to enter the US on a visitor visa with "immigrant intent". The result is that attempting to adjust status after entering as a visitor and marrying stands a good chance of being accused of immigration fraud.

> Do I have any tax exposure

Gifts in the US are not taxable for the recipient, but they can be taxable for the giver. I do not know what the rules for Indian's are.

> or problems with accepting this money?

The fundamental problem is that your "boyfriend"'s story doesn't pass the sniff test.

There are a few possibilities, none of them good for you.

1. The money doesn't exist at all, it's just part of a story. The boyfriend will come up with excuses about why they can't access the money and/or about you needing to pay fees before you can access it. Fake banks may well become involved.
2. You appear to receive the money and the "boyfriend" asks you to send some of it onwards spend it on items for him or whatever. Some time later the transaction transferring the money to you turns out to be fraudulent and is reversed. You are still on the hook for the spending.
3. You receive the money, but it turns out to be associated with serious crime of some sort. You get dragged into a criminal investigation.

Personally I suspect this is the first case, the impression I get is that thieves and scammers like to work in the thousands of dollars. Enough money that the enterprise is profitable for the scammers, not so much as to throw up massive red flags everywhere.

Comment: Good answer and advice for future visitors (+1), unfortunately [J David](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/64236/j-david) hasn't been around for 5 years.. The obvious reason is that they already married the nigerian prince with billions instead.. ;)