# I would like to know if this bank is legitamate?

Tags: banking

I need to check to see if this back is legitimate.  My boyfriend has over a million dollars in this bank MBFBonline?  They locked his account because the company he worked for in Berlin sent all his money at once.  Now he is in Berlin and can't access his account because it is frozen.  He has to pay taxes before he can leave and he can't get to his money.  I need to know if this is a scam.

Comment: This is a scam. The person speaking to you is not your boyfriend. 'he' is likely to be multiple people working together in an organized crime ring to scam others. You must cease all communication with him immediately. Be on the lookout for future contact from others, who will really be the same person(s), although they may pretend to be entirely different groups.

Comment: Another similar story: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/86668/us-citizen-receiving-bank-transfer-from-foreign-boyfriend?rq=1

Comment: This is a scam, people who have millions of dollars don't need your help to transfer money.

Comment: Whatever else you choose to do, _don't_ pay the taxes that your "boyfriend" says he must pay before he can leave Berlin on your boyfriend's behalf, and don't send him the money to pay those taxes either.

Answer (score 3):

A whois search (https://www.whois.com/whois/mbfbonline.com) says that MBFBonline is a domain hosted by NAMECHEAPHOSTING.COM that has existed for a relatively short time (2020). It claims to be based in Reykjavik. So I would bet that it's fake.

But the whole pattern here is of a standard romance scam (https://fightcybercrime.org/scams/imposter/romance-scams)

This person is not your friend.

See past answers for some of the other questions that you should have asked that should have warned you.

At least you asked in time.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. NameCheap is one of the most popular domain registrars/web-hosts, plenty of legitimate businesses use them. This is clearly a scam, but not because of who the domain registrar/web-host is.

Comment: I would be shocked if a major business like a bank, which is betting millions per day on their services being operational, would use a discount registrar. If you can find me a counterexample I'll withdraw my answer.

Comment: The fain was also created recently, which was also reason for concern. And appears to have already been shut down, which closes the question.

Comment: Namecheap is 2nd in popularity to GoDaddy (which Ally and Quontic use). I'm not going to search other banks, registrar is not a good indicator of anything. The site being recently created (2020) is something you could have pointed to as evidence, but you claimed that the domain registrar is enough to immediately know.

Comment: If I could still find the record I'd update my answer. Since it seems to be gone the question is mostly moot. But I stand by my answer; you are free to downvote. We agree that we disagree.